# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here is my purpose, read a mysql table(50 million+ rows) to hdfs.

spark version:3.0.3

```
object DBHelper {
  def setConnectionProperty(): Properties = {
    val connProp = new Properties
    connProp.put("driver", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")
    connProp.put("user", System.getProperty("db_user"))
    connProp.put("password", System.getProperty("db_password"))
    connProp
  }
}
```

When I submit spark task(master yarn --deploy-mode client) and call the method "loadUserVerifyData" in main and read 1000(or more less), spent 20m+ and still throws exception "org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:"

```
def loadUserVerifyData(spark: SparkSession, args: Array[String]): Unit = {
val tableName = args(0)

//分区数
val partitionNum = args(1).toInt

val idRange = CMOrderLog.getIDRange(tableName, URL)

//ID值起始范围
val start = idRange.get(0)
val end = idRange.get(0)

val originDF = spark.read.jdbc(URL, tableName, "id", start, end, partitionNum, DBHelper.setConnectionProperty)

originDF.createOrReplaceTempView(tableName)

val context = originDF.sqlContext
context.udf.register("e_name", (str: String) => StringUtils.encrypt(str, 1))
context.udf.register("e_card", (str: String) => StringUtils.encrypt(str))

val sql = "SELECT t.*, e_name(t.auth_realname) as real_name, e_card(t.auth_person_card) as id_card FROM " + tableName + " t"

val finalDF = context.sql(sql).drop("auth_realname", "auth_person_card")

finalDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(OUTPUT + tableName)

spark.stop()
}
```

Exception logs:

```
2018-08-26 16:15:02 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - ResultStage 0 (parquet at ReadDb2HDFS.scala:288) failed in 1008.933 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, master, executor 4): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 4 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 130349 ms
Driver stacktrace:
2018-08-26 16:15:02 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - Job 0 failed: parquet at ReadDb2HDFS.scala:288, took 1008.977605 s
2018-08-26 16:15:02 ERROR FileFormatWriter:91 - Aborting job null.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, master, executor 4): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 4 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 130349 ms
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1587)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1820)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1769)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1758)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2027)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:547)
    at com.cm.data.datasync.ReadDb2HDFS$.loadUserBaseData(ReadDb2HDFS.scala:288)
    at com.cm.data.datasync.ReadDb2HDFS$.main(ReadDb2HDFS.scala:55)
    at com.cm.data.datasync.ReadDb2HDFS.main(ReadDb2HDFS.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:879)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Comment: Hi, please edit the question to include the exception logs as they seem to have got missed off. Thanks.

Comment: thx remind!  this my first use.

Comment: Please provide the schema of finalDF and try to perform some action on finalDF like count before write and see if this is working, please send the error if you are getting after doing count as I don’t see any issues in writing.

Comment: @WilliamChan try increasing the executor memory and while reading from JDBC from spark all the connections made to RDBMS are single threaded. You can achieve better performance if you set --executor-cores 1, --num-executors (equal to partitionNum), lower bound(start) to 0 and upper bound(end) equal to partitionNum and set fetchsize=10000 (or more) property in DBHelper.setConnectionProperty

Comment: @MansoorBabaShaik Thank you for response.here is my spark submit command: spark-submit --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Ddb_user=***** -Ddb_password=*****" --master yarn --deploy-mode client --packages "mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.6" --num-executors 4 --executor-memory 4G --class "com.cm.data.datasync.ReadDb2HDFS" /home/ubuntu/target/data_analysis-1.0.2.jar user_base 4 1 1000.   And I had try your advice to set fitchsize property in DBHelper and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Chandan Thanks. the finalDF's schema is just the table's nothing special. that you sad, I had done some action finalDF before write like count and show etc.. show is ok, but count throw exception like write. so this issue confuse me a while time.

Comment: @William Chan --driver-memory 4G --num-executors 8  --executor-cores 1 --executor-memory 4G.....you need set fetchsize property in DBHelper.setConnectionProperty to 10000...........If still it don't work please provide me DBHelper.setConnectionProperty function definition.

Comment: @MansoorBabaShaik, Hi, pls look of my supplement, on top. I think i got ur mean, you want to set fetchsize property to load `fetchsize value`datas once. I think so if it work. and I use another method to read table "val originDF = spark.read.jdbc(URL, tableName, predicates, DBHelper.setConnectionProperty)" it is ok.

Comment: I think that two method different is load whole date in memory and load a part of date by your assign range in memory. Obviously, throws excpetion(OOM) method is 'spark.read.jdbc(URL, tableName, "id", start, end, partitionNum, DBHelper.setConnectionProperty)'. If 'fetchsize' property work,it won't throws exception. I will research 'fitchsize' somethime. BTW, yesterday i not went to work. Thank you~@MansoorBabaShaik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this property

```
connProp.put("fetchsize", "10000")
```

and your job with this spark config:

```
--driver-memory 4G --num-executors 8 --executor-cores 1 --executor-memory 4G
```

pass arguments

```
start=0; end = 8; partitionNum=8
```

and provide me logs if any exceptions occur.